# How do I display a (R) or (TM) symbol on SE sites?

Tags: support, markdown, special-characters

In normal html I just show this character - &#174

How to do it on SE sites?

I see the problem now.  I was trying to do it in a quote.  As in quoting another source.  That seems to cause an issue for me.

But without using the char codes and pasting in the character it seems to work.

> &reg  does not work here in quotes but ®  does

"& # 174" seems to work -> &#174

&reg works here?

EDIT

In my defense - I'm just a C++ developer - not an html/css jscript webby guy.

Comment: You do it like this .. ®

Comment: If you want to add the ® symbol after each brand, language etc... you are ahead of a lot of pain :-)

Comment: I voted to close as well.  I couldn;t delete it.  I th ought there was a specific issue about markdown in the quoted text.  I guess I am just not so good at the internets

Comment: Internets 1 - Tim 0, Better luck next time.  `:P`

Comment: Try *the* Internet...

Comment: In a quote, &reg doesn't work but &reg; does work (at least in the preview pane).

Answer (score 35):

You can use HTML entities:

© - `&copy;`
® - `&reg;`
™ - `&trade;` (or `<sup>TM</sup>` if you're hacky)

Of course, you can just copy them from elsewhere and paste here:

© ® ™

Comment: Some of us prefer raw, unadorned ALT codes.

Comment: New view source link (after the MSE/MSO split): https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/fb3ea079-956a-4f83-bf55-7b9f51b4dfab/view-source